# Using substr to search first three characters of array

Tags: php

I am making a simple zip code lookup for rates. The code below functions, basically if the first 3 characters from $zipcode are "962" ( or whatever is determined ) it echos the text. Is there a way to clean this up?

How can I make $zipcode look through a array to see if any of the conditions are true?

```
if (substr($zipcode, 0, 3) === '962' || substr($zipcode, 0, 3) === '963' || substr($zipcode, 0, 3) === '964' || substr($zipcode, 0, 3) === '964' || substr($zipcode, 0, 3) === '965' || substr($zipcode, 0, 3) === '966') {
echo "We do not ship FPO";
}
```

Comment: I think you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for questions like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply put list of unsupported zip prefixes into and array and check the prefix provided against this array.

```
$zip_prefix_no_ship = array('962', '963', '964', '965', '966');
$zip_prefix = substr($zip_code, 0, 3);
if(in_array($zip_prefix, $zip_prefix_no_ship)) {
    echo "We do not ship FPO"
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this one to help. Ranges will do find with this condition, but a few others would not work. Thanks everyone for the help and Mike thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (in_array(substr($zipcode, 0, 3), range(962, 966))) {
    echo 'We do not ship FPO';
}
```

Or, cleaned up a bit:

```
$needle = substr($zipcode, 0, 3);
$haystack = range(962, 966);
if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
    echo 'We do not ship FPO';
}
```

[**in_array()**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.in-array.php) checks if a value exists in an array.

[**range()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) creates an array of values between the two values provided.

If the array of numbers you want to check against will not always be a sequential set of numbers, then you could change `range(962, 966)` to `array(962, 963, ... )`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
if(preg_match('/^96[2-6]/', $zipcode)) {
    echo "We do not ship FPO";
}
```